# What's the best way to present variables in a WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: tags, text-editor, code, wysiwyg

I'm working on a WYSIWYG editor, similar to [medium.com](http://medium.com). We need to support variables inside the editor. For example, you might want to add text: `Hi, *|FNAME|*` which would be replaced with `Hi, Gustavs` depending on who views it.

What's the best way to visually present it? Do you know any sites that do that?

We don't want to use `*|TagsLikeThis|*`, because it doesn't give the impression that it will be replaced with the real content later.

Comment: How well are the users versed in programming languages? I know some PHP so if dynamic variable would have something like this $FNAME making your tag look like this = *|$FNAME|* would make me aware that it will change.

Comment: I would like to show something different than [[first name]] or \*|FNAME|\* or anything else like that. I want it to say "Hi, Gustavs", but somehow show that it will change based on who sees it.

Comment: That was not Igor's question, the question is if your users are going to be people that are familiar with programming languages, or something else that you can use as a syntax hook for them to understand what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For replacements I always prefer to use double square brackets with natural language:

```
Hello, [[first name]]
```

Double brackets rarely appear in normal text but are easy to type and read, natural language removes the need to know/lookup field names.

Alternatively you can use real data with highlighting and some tool-tips,  bit trickier to implement but much richer for the user.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fusLNj.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: I would like to show something different than [[first name]] or \*|FNAME|\* or anything else like that. I want it to say "Hi, Gustavs", but somehow show that it will change based on who sees it.

Comment: @GustavsCirulis Added alternative.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1 - Show variables as in templating languages**

[image]

For a programmer this is easy to understand, but for a casual user this might be the first time they have ever used a variable. The biggest downside is that users may edit the variable, for example entering {{TMIE}} instead and wonder why it won't work. Another downside is that it looks very technical and might dissuade some users from using the app.

**Option 2 - Mimic Facebook tagging**

In Facebook if you type the name of a user or a page, the whole mention becomes a tag that can be deleted as a unit. If the cursor is placed after the tag and backspace is pressed, the whole tag is deleted.

[image]

In the example case it might appear like this:

[image]

This communicates to the user at least that "this is something you can't modify except as a unit". Besides being a lot more difficult to implement, another downside is that this tag should not be possible to delete, as it wouldn't be clear how to add it again.

**Option 3 - Split text into before-variable and after-variable**

This option looks super ugly, but it has the benefit of making it impossible to mess up the variable AND being very easy to implement.

[image]